# SSAS - Use named set to define allowed role dimension data

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a named set defined as follows:

```
CREATE DYNAMIC SET CURRENTCUBE.[PermissionTest]
 AS [Clients].[Client Group ID].&[4] ;
```

In the Role - Dimension Data dialog of [Clients].[Client Group ID] I would like use the Named Set, instead of writing [Clients].[Client Group ID].&[4].

Is it possible to reference a named set in a Role Definition?

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't working then I wouldn't be surprised. Mosha documented the order of cube initialization tasks [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160326013832/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2005/12/31/default-members-mdx-scripts-security-kpis-and-perspectives.aspx). Note the MDX script executes after security is applied.